# Issue with chart.Drawdown in performance analytics, need finite 'ylim' values error

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

So I am currently trying to create a Drawdown graph for daily profit/loss. Using:

```
cols = rainbow(ncol(pdrawdown),s=0.7, v=0.8, alpha= 0.7)
chart.Drawdown(pdrawdown, legend.loc = "bottomleft",colorset = cols,
               main = "Drawdown Chart", xlab ="Date", ylab = "Drawdown")
```

I was able to easily plot it for returns (whose values are for the most part less than 10). However, upon trying to use this exact same method for profit/loss, whose values reach the range of 10e+09, I get the error:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, xaxs = "r", log = logaxis) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
```

The weirdest part about this is that when I simply divide every value in my data table pdrawdown by 10,000,000 with `pdrawdown = pdrawdown/10000000`, the issue is solved and it can plot it. So what can I do to plot the graph properly without having to use this weird hack?

Answer (score 3):

Is your time series `pdrawdown` a series of values (e.g. [100, 101, 99.5, 102, ... ]) or is it a series of percentage changes (e.g [0.01, -0.02, 0.025, ...]) ?

chart.Drawdown needs a series of percentage changes. When you have a series of absolute values, chart.Drawdown will assume them to be percentage changes and the results will therefore become so large that you get a `need finite 'ylim' values` error.

Comment: Agreed, this is usually the issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply set a ylim value?

```
chart.Drawdown(pdrawdown, legend.loc = "bottomleft",colorset = cols,
           main = "Drawdown Chart", xlab ="Date", ylab = "Drawdown", 
                   ylim=c(0,1000000000))
```

Comment: This didn't work, though thanks for the attempt. For some reason it looks like it spikes to massive numbers that cannot be fitted onto a scale, before returning to 0.